# Ansible nested variables in command line

Tags: variables, nested, ansible

I have some variables in my playbook as follows:

`---
first_var:
  param1: value1
  param2: value2`

And I want to call these parametres from the commandline as follows:

`ansible-playbook -i inventory site.yml -e 'first_var.param1=newvalue1'`

But doesn't work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this only if you modify [hash-behaviour](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) to `merge` (**this can potentialy brake your playbooks**).
Also for this to work, you need to pass extra variables as JSON object, this will not work for `-e var=value`.

Example command line:

```
ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "{'first_var':{'param1':'newvalue1'}}" site.yml
```

Comment: That's it, Thank you very much (^_^)